# Android EditText Dynamicaly changing text to Emoticons

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, emoticons

how can i change Dynamically the text written in the edit to an Emoticon...
Ex: "nice to meet you :) "  = Dynamic Result "nice to meet you [pic]smiley[pic]":

```
    Editest.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {

        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {


        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Hint to do so:

What you might be able to do is create a custom Manager that is a container for EditFields and BitmapFields. When the user clicks in the initial EditField that is inside of your Manager and begins typing, you let them type until they want an emoticon. When they select it you create a BitmapField right after the EditField and then place a new EditField to the right of the BitmapField. You'll have to keep track of things like when the user hits backspace and empties an EditField, it should be removed, and then they are selecting the BitmapField, and a subsequent backspace would delete the BitmapField and put focus on the previous EditField.

You will have to also create your own EditField that you can control the size of, and BitmapField that allows for backspace to delete it.

As far as I can think ahead, you shouldn't have any problem using this for 5.0

Edit for comments:

You'll have to be implementing your own sublayout() of your Manager in any approach you take, so you know positions because you're the one who put them there. If you want to want to do multi-line (my approach was for single-line), you can do one of three things:

1. Just have new EditFields for each line and do the linking the
   same way I talked about where
   backspace drops you to the previous
   Field, in this case the last line.
   You have to keep measurements of how
   big the field is based off of the
   text, and see if that will move it
   to the next line. If it does just
   adjust where the EditFields are
   positioned.
2. You can do your image placement in
   the multi-line field by
       implementing your own EditField that
       expands height, in which case you'll
       know where the text is and what
       lines you are on. Drawing the Bitmap
       would be a matter of calculating
       (what line number you are) * (font
       height) and
       getAdvance(text_up_to_bitmap).
3. Implement your own EditField where
   you have a focusable Manager
       that you manually do all of the
       drawing. You can parse a String that
       you save from capturing key strokes
       and maybe have a flag where an
       emoticon should be. Draw the text
       before it, draw the emoticon, then
       continue drawing the text. The
       difficulty with this is you will
       have to do things like determining
       where the cursor should be, bringing
       up the virtual keyboard, and
       handling some of the other tasks
       that the EditField does for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) to scan the text for the string ":)" and then replace it with [smiley](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).

As I don't know what your app is exactly doing I cannot say if it is a good idea to use a TextWatcher as it will fire each time a character is/was entered. Perhaps it might be better to do the replacement after a certain event like pressing an OK button or when the TextView loses focus.

Comment: I am doin a Chat App so i want the emoticon to appear when i smiley sign is typed ...

Comment: Ok, so I guess you got a EditText view where the user types in the  message and some kind of other view which shows the chat protocol (This view must be capable of showing images and text). If this is you setup I would do the replacement after the user pressed the sent button as you cannot display images in a EditText. By this way you only have to scan the text one time for smilies as characters.